# Catching an exception from a method

Tags: c#, exception, try-catch

I'm using a library that throws an exception when an ApiKey doesn't work. Let's say the library has a method called GetAppels(). If the ApiKey isn't valid it returns a message exception, in this case "forbidden".

Notice that GetAppels() is throwing the exception.

Now I would like to know when the ApiKey isn't valid, so I can tell the user that's using a wrong key.

So I did this.

```
try{
   apiTest api = new apiTest(Key.Text);
   api.GetAppels();
} catch (Exception) { MessageBox.Show("Wrong key!"); }
```

but this doesn't work, for some reason it continues throwing the other exception before this one. Which it makes sense because the try inside GetAppels is going first than my own try/catch. How could I solve this? How could I catch when the method GetAppels (which isn't the method itself but another one inside this) throws an exception?

EDIT:

GetAppels() method was just an example, this is how the method throws the exception actually.

```
protected void HandleRequestFailure(HttpResponseMessage response)
{
    try
    {
        if (response.StatusCode == (HttpStatusCode)429)
        {
            var retryAfter = TimeSpan.Zero;
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("Retry-After", out var retryAfterHeaderValues))
            {
                if (int.TryParse(retryAfterHeaderValues.FirstOrDefault(), out var seconds))
                {
                    retryAfter = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds);
                }
            }

            string rateLimitType = null;
            if (response.Headers.TryGetValues("X-Rate-Limit-Type", out var rateLimitTypeHeaderValues))
            {
                rateLimitType = rateLimitTypeHeaderValues.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            throw new RiotSharpRateLimitException("429, Rate Limit Exceeded", response.StatusCode, retryAfter, rateLimitType);
        }
        else if (RiotHttpStatusCodeResponse.Contains(response.StatusCode))
        {
            string message;
            try // try get error message from response
            {
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
                message = obj["status"]["message"].ToObject<string>();
            }
            catch {
                message = response.StatusCode.ToString();
            }
            throw new RiotSharpException(message, response.StatusCode);
        }
        else
            throw new RiotSharpException("Unexpeced failure", response.StatusCode);
    }
    finally
    {
        response.Dispose(); //Dispose Response On Error
    }
}
```

This is how I'm catching the exception, maybe I'm doing something wrong.

```
private bool CheckAPIKEY(string key)
{
    try
    {
        riotApi = RiotApi.GetDevelopmentInstance(key);
        riotApi.Summoner.GetSummonerByNameAsync(
            region: RiotSharp.Misc.Region.Euw, 
            summonerName: summonerName
        );

        return true;
    }
    catch (RiotSharpException) { return false; }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    if (gameIsRunning)
        MessageBox.Show("Program is already running!");
    else if (summonerName != null) 
    {
        KEY = Key.Text;

        if(!CheckAPIKEY(KEY))
            MessageBox.Show("Your Riot API Key isn't valid.");          
    }
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Couldn't recive information about your SummonerName, is your League of legends game opened?");
}
```

Comment: How does it throw it? Does it throw the method or does it catch it without rethrowing, effectively not throwing an exception? Can you show the implementation of `GetAppels`?

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank I've edited the post with the code!

Comment: @HappyMoose `RiotSharp.RiotSharpException: 'Forbidden'`

Comment: Your inner method doesn't catch (or swallow) the exception, it simply throws it. So you should definitely be able to catch it with `catch(Exception)` or `catch(RiotSharpException)`

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank I've added a bit of code of how I'm catching the exception, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: You are never calling `HandleRequestFailure` (at least not in the code that you have shown), consequently never throwing the exception.

Comment: @ef-dknittl-frank I assume that `GetSummonerByNameAsync()` is doing it internally since it throws me that exception. I just tried to delete `riotApi.Summoner.GetSummonerByNameAsync()` line and got not exceptions.

Comment: It looks like the problem is that you're calling an async method within a synchronous method, therefore your code is finishing execution before the exception is thrown. You should either change your method to async and await it (preferred) or change your code to use .GetAwaiter().GetResult()

Comment: @ye-olde-dev Yikes, you're right, how could I not realize. Feel free to answer to the post so I can put your reply as the correct one

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling an async method and not awaiting the result in any way. You can do either of the following, though the first is preferred by most .NET devs I know.

```cs
private async Task<bool> CheckAPIKEY(string key)
{
    try
    {
        riotApi = RiotApi.GetDevelopmentInstance(key);
        await riotApi.Summoner.GetSummonerByNameAsync(
            region: RiotSharp.Misc.Region.Euw, 
            summonerName: summonerName
        );

        return true;
    }
    catch (RiotSharpException) { return false; }
}
```

or this

```cs
private bool CheckAPIKEY(string key)
{
    try
    {
        riotApi = RiotApi.GetDevelopmentInstance(key);
        riotApi.Summoner.GetSummonerByNameAsync(
            region: RiotSharp.Misc.Region.Euw, 
            summonerName: summonerName
        )
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();


        return true;
    }
    catch (RiotSharpException) { return false; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
private bool API(string a)
{
    try
    {
        Api = WebApi.GetDevelopmentInstance(a);
        Api.Summoner.GetSummonerByNameAsync(
            region: WebApi.Misc.Region.Euw, 
            summonerName: summonerName
        )
        .GetAwaiter()
        .GetResult();


        return true;
    }
    catch (WebApiException) { return false; }
}
```